# How to hide a div on click outside of it except few links in angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have few links coming from loop,once I click to those links a div will be showing on each time.But here I need to hide the div once I click outside anywhere except on links.Here is the code below.When I click on 'click-1',div will show,again when I click 'click-2',other div will show..so on
https://plnkr.co/edit/jv7uKHlryMnkJgK9wVM6?p=preview

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
   <div class="maindiv" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in data" >
       <div ng-click="setActiveItem(x)" class="id">Click-{{x.id}}</div>
       &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ssssssssssss
       <div class="arrow_box name" ng-show="activeItem==x">
       <h3>{{x.name}}</h3>
       <p>Hello world</p>
       <h3>{{x.name}}</h3>
       <p>Hello world</p>
       <h3>{{x.name}}</h3>
       <p>Hello world</p>
       </div>
    </li>
  </ul>  
</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

### SCRIPT.JS

```
var data = [{"name":"name1","title":"title1","id":"1"},{"name":"name2","title":"title2","id":"2"},{"name":"name3","title":"title3","id":"3"}];
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.data = data;

  $scope.setActiveItem = function(item){
     $scope.activeItem = item;
  }

  // show first on page load
  // $scope.activeItem = data[0];

});// Code goes here
```

### STYLE.CSS

```
ul li{
list-style-type:none;
cursor:pointer;
}
ul{
margin:0;
}
.maindiv{
position:relative;
}
.name{
position: absolute;
    left: 97px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 61px;
    height: 202px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 24%;
}
.arrow_box {
    position: absolute;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
    right: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow_box:after {
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-right-color: #000000;
    border-width: 5px;
    margin-top: -5px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-right-color: #000000;
    border-width: 8px;
    margin-top: -8px;
}
.id,name{
float:left;
}
```

Comment: Read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Answer (score 0):

If i understood right, you could try displaying an overlay when you open your "arrow_box" that would catch a click event to hide it and close the "arrow_box".

I've updated your plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/CHk6atcGYLykpeXN7Z1g?p=preview

The key elements are those :

The overlay :

```
<div class="overlay" ng-show="activeItem!=null" ng-click="setActiveItem(null)"></div>
```

The corresponding css :

```
.overlay{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  z-index:1;
}
```

The modified arrow_box css :

```
.arrow_box {
    position: absolute;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    z-index:10;                <------ the modification
}
```

Notice that also moved your `ng-app` and `ng-controller`.

Hope this helps